# Подсветка синтаксиса для Java через HTML

Tags: java, html

Сам код работает, но не работает с EditText:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><p style=\\"color:#FF0000\\">Test</p></html>"));
```

Comment: Используемую GUI-библиотеку, видимо, надо угадать. Android?

Comment: И что именно означает "не работает с EditText"?